# R: webscraping into a tree of list with elements and subelements

Tags: r, list, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

Using `rvest`, I scraped a webpage with **4** tables (`<table class="ed-board-table">`) and **n** number of `<td class="ed-board-member">`.

I wish to put this into a list of **4** elements and **n** subelements.

I.e., my goal is to have a list (called `editors`) in a tree of elements and sub-elements like this:

```
editors

[[1]] # Table 1
[1] #Content 1 of Table 1
[2] #Content 2 of Table 1


[[2]] # Table 2
[1] #Content 1 of Table 2
[2] #Content 2 of Table 2
[3] #Content 3 of Table 2

[[3]] # Table 3
[1] #Content 1 of Table 3

[[4]] # Table 4
[1] #Content 1 of Table 4
```

My code so far, using [this website](https://journals.sagepub.com/editorial-board/asr), fails to accomplish this:

```
# extract the relevant part of the webpage [WORKS FINE]
webpage <- read_html(url("https://journals.sagepub.com/editorial-board/asr")) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="5dfa7b11-3157-4585-b786-54aa88233446"]/div/div/div')

# extract 4 tables into a list of 4 elements [WORKS FINE]
editors <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="//table[@class='ed-board-table']")

# extract the tables' n contents into n subelements [DOES NOT WORK]
editors2 <- sapply(editors,
                  function(x)
                  {
                    x %>%
                      html_nodes(xpath="//td[@class='ed-board-member']")
                  }
)
```

The result is, unfortunately, a list of **4** elements (which is correct), *each of which* contains the contents from `<td class="ed-board-member">` from *all* tables.

How can I accomplish to have a list of **4** elements (of `<table>`) with only those subelements (of `<td>`) that belong to the *respective* element/table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
read_html("https://journals.sagepub.com/editorial-board/asr") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class='editorial-board']/descendant::table") %>%  
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```